# Objective-C: Equivalent to stringWithFormat for NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring, stringwithformat

I am trying to add a hyperlink in a string. I have a localized string and I put %@ to format my string. When I add the attributed string into my string, the attributed format gives the raw result which is `NSLink = "https://www.example.com"`. I could not find an attributed string formatter the same as the string formatter. How can I achieve the same behaviour in my case?

Code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Example"];
[str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"https:/www.example.com" range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
NSMutableAttributedString *originalStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: self.pageDescriptions[3].localized];
pageContentViewController.messageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:self.pageDescriptions[index].localized, str];
```

Answer (score 0):

`stringWithFormat:` is only doing substitutions of formatters. So if your formatters are simple enough, like a `%@`, you can just search for it with [`rangeOfString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410144-rangeofstring?language=occ) and do the substitution yourself with [`replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1417045-replacecharactersinrange?language=occ).

```
NSMutableAttributedString *strWithLink = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Example"];
[strWithLink addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"https:/www.example.com" range:NSMakeRange(0, strWithLink.length)];

NSMutableAttributedString *strWithFormat = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"hello %@ world"];
[strWithFormat replaceCharactersInRange:[strWithFormat.string rangeOfString:@"%@"] withAttributedString:strWithLink];
```

The result here in `strWithFormat` kept the attributes of `strWithLink`.

Note: this won't work correctly if your format is complex, like with `%%@ %@ %%@`, because it will replace the first occurrence of `%@`, while `stringWithFormat:` would have replaced the middle occurrence.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't one. You create the NSAttributedString by hand, or you create an extension that does what you want if you do this a lot.